# Maven resolution of snapshots when non-snapshot version exists

Tags: maven

Say "MyProject" depends on "n-SNAPSHOT" version of ProjectA. ProjectA is parallelly developed(by other team) and graduates as "n" from "n-SNAPSHOT" and is released to the repository. Can a maven extension be written that could fetch version "n" of ProjectA (though the pom of MyProject has version as "n-SNAPSHOT"for ProjectA) once "n" is released / "n-SNAPSHOT" is removed? Are there any pitfalls / downsides in doing this?

Comment: Take a look at the `versions-maven-plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT or 1.0.0 (when this is released), you can use a version range

```
[1.0.0-SNAPSHOT,1.0.0]
```

This automatically resolves to a version from this range (the highest that is found, if no other constraints are given). The downside is that it obstructs dependency mediation: If some other transitive dependency of your project is [2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, 2.0.0], the build will fail.